# Disabling transparency in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency

I am working on an application that is themeable, so it is impossible for me to pick a color that is guaranteed to not exist. Unfortunately, I can't find an option to disable the transparency key on a form. If I set the transparency key to transparent, I have the issue shown below:

[image]

Comment: I think it's safe to make one out of the 16.7 million possible colour combinations transparent (`0xFF00FF`, for instance).

Comment: Just specify that the users theming the application cannot use a certain value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would `Form.AllowTransparency` do the job?